# Poltergeist and use onResourceReceived function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

In my project I must scraping some pages. I'm using Capybara with phantomjs for this. I have one problem, some of this pages send async (XHR) requests and I need to block them.

I found solution for this case. Phantomjs can handle request and abort it - https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onResourceReceived

I wrote js script to log and abort requests:

```js
page.onResourceRequested = function(request, net) {
  console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(requestData));
  net.abort();
};
```

and add it to init driver (https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization)

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
    :phantomjs_options => ['--debug=no',
                           '--load-images=no',
                           '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
                           '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],
    extensions: [File.expand_path("../lib/phantomjs/abort_async.js", __FILE__)],
    :debug => false,
    js_errors: false)
end
```

But it isn't working...
I think that problem is with js variable `page` because this variale is not defined

Comment: Hello @Fist! Do you managed to get this working?

Comment: No, I'm still waiting for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

The **extensions:** option is just to preload some javascript files within the browser !

To load some js preferences, rewrite your query like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
    :phantomjs_options => [File.expand_path("../lib/phantomjs/abort_async.js", __FILE__),
                        '--debug=no',
                        '--load-images=no',
                        '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
                        '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],
    extensions: [],
    :debug => false,
    js_errors: false)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

poltergeist now supports **url blacklisting** and **whitelisting**, same as capybara-webkit does.
(https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#url-blacklisting)

```
page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = ['http://www.example.com']
```

You can blacklist the server URL for the async request. the [spec file](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/spec/integration/driver_spec.rb) might be a help to understand those features.